Prevent Horizontal Scroll During Column Resizing
First of all, I use Tabulator v5.4.4 and layout is fitColumns.
I want to use the resizableColumnFit option for column resizing, but this feature does not completely solve the white space problem or horizontal scrolling that occurs during resizing.
For example, when I set resizableColumnFit as true and mark the last column as resizable = false, the white space problem disappears.
However, when I expand a column, I cannot prevent the horizontal scrolling. When this happens, I need a scroll operation to display the columns on the right.
When all columns are marked as resizable, I could not find a solution for the white space on the right.
As a workaround for this situation, I can calculate the remaining white space in the columnResized event and update the width of the last column. However, I am not sure if this will confuse the library's own calculations.


let data = [{
        name: 'name',
        progress: 8,
    gender: 'm',
    rating: 5,
    col: 'blue',
    dob: '1/1/2000'
}];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    data:data,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    resizableColumnFit: true,
    columns:[
    {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:'input', resizable:true},
    {title:"Progress", field:"progress", sorter:"number", resizable:true},
    {title:"Gender", field:"gender", resizable:true},
    {title:"Rating", field:"rating", resizable:true},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", resizable:true},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", hozAlign:"center", resizable:true},
    ],
});

table.on("columnResized", function (data) {
    StretchLastColumn();
});

function StretchLastColumn() {
    // Get the total width of the table
    var tableWidth = document.getElementById("example-table").offsetWidth;

    // Calculate the total width of all columns except the last one
    var columns = table.getColumns();

    var totalWidth = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length - 1; i++) {
        totalWidth += columns[i].getWidth();
    }


    // Set the width of the last column
    var lastColumn = columns[columns.length - 1];
    var remainingWidth = tableWidth - totalWidth;
    if (remainingWidth > 0) {
        lastColumn.setWidth(remainingWidth);
    }
    //column - column component of the resized column
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.4.4/css/tabulator.min.css" integrity="sha512-j3rR7zfij45jvjB25No5oizV4tdpt6buwLrvfhXXboG+F88VMnvA4TsJpKgChHa156f+6gYk951Cv5pInltllQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.4.4/js/tabulator.min.js" integrity="sha512-BGo9xGWI32ZfTMp/ueR3fZKO5nYkPbt3uwMWr+w8w3e72H8A0sTQGO+iqRADwIT0eJkFP1HDgSC82gA4sTuQ6w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <div id="example-table"></div>



In short, what I want to do is: to resize the columns, but to prevent resize when the horizontal scrolling occurs.
Is there a solution for this in the library?
